# Rails 4 Active Admin i18n filters with Active Record Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, filter, internationalization, activeadmin

I need to translate the labels for my filters as shown in the screenshot. Although the model names and their foreign keys are translated in my pl.yml file the names are still in english. The filters generated here are the default ones. I've tried to follow the i18n process by using this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models.

[image]

So far I've tried something like this:

```
pl:
 activerecord:
  models:
   admin:
    user:
     one: Użytkownik
     other: Użytkownicy
     many: Użytkownicy
     few: Użytkownicy
```

but then I keep getting an error:

`" translation data {:user=>{:one=>"Użytkownik", :other=>"Użytkownicy", :few=>"Użytkownicy", :many=>"Użytkownicy"}} can not be used with :count=>2.1".`

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `many` and `few` key, then it should be work.

```
pl:
 activerecord:
  models:
   admin:
    user:
     one: Użytkownik
     other: Użytkownicy
```

Comment: Unfortunately the error stays the same:

    translation data {:user=>{:one=>"Użytkownik",  :other=>"Użytkownicy"}}     can not be used with :count => 2.1 `

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are using namespace.
So try in following manner, it is working for me.

```
pl:
 activerecord:
  models:
   admin/user:
    one: Użytkownik
    other: Użytkownicy
```

Now check in your console

```
Admin::User.model_name.human(count: 2)
       or
Admin::User.model_name.human
```

Comment: Ok so the app doesn't crash this time, the label is still not translated and when I typed in the console the code you wrote above I get an error:

NameError: uninitialized constant Admin::User

Comment: Ok, can you please share how exactly you defined user class? and structure.

Comment: Sure, here's my user.rb model: 

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dde8f567a243b2cfb41d

and here's my Model Dependency Diagram if you need it:

http://oi58.tinypic.com/149vbjn.jpg

Comment: So it seems like there is no namespace it is directly under models. So you can remove admin and instead of 'admin/user:' use 'user:' in pl.yml. and from console use User.model_name.human(count: 2)

Comment: Yeah I've tried translating all the model names in the active admin panel by using the following code:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/594ca9797bff58261190

But the problem is - although the model names get translated in the top bar and everywhere else, in the filters they are still not. Take a look:

http://oi62.tinypic.com/2d7ydxj.jpg

And after calling User.model_name.human(count: 2) in the console I get the polish name "Użytkownicy" so no idea why it's not translated in the filters.

Comment: I didn't see any issue in your yml file. I think you just have to revisit your .erb file where you have the placed your filter related code.

Comment: The thing is as I mentioned in my post I don't generate any filters, I use the defaults (I guess I will have to define my own custom filters to fix this issue probably).

Here have a look at the code for a receipt in the admin panel:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/38b0b5c9925beb0e4782

Answer (score 0):

You need to translate the model attributes just like this:

```
pl:
 activerecord:
  models:
   admin/user:
    one: Użytkownik
    other: Użytkownicy
  attributes:
    admin/user:
      user: # your translation
      complaint: #your translation
```

Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: I'm afraid not, still they don't get translated (I do not get any errors though).